# Need help understanding Kernel Transport speed on GPU (numba, cupy, cuda)

Tags: numpy, gpu, numba, cupy

While GPUs speed math calculations there is a fixed overhead for moving a kernel out to the GPU for execution that is high.

I'm using cupy and numba.  THe first time I execute a function call that is using cupy's GPU version of numpy it is quite slow. But the second time it is fast.

I've realized I don't understand how the kernel, or GPU code, gets out to the GPU to run.  Operationally I want to understand this better so that I can know when the things I do will accidentally create a slow step due to some kernel transfer.  So I need some sorts of rules or rules of thumb understand the concept.

For example, if I multiply two cupy arrays that are stashed on the GPU already I might write C= A*B

At some point the cupy overload on * multiplication has to be coded out on the GPU, and it automagically needs will also get wrapped by loops that break it down into blocks and threads.  So presumably this code is some kernel that gets transported out to the GPU.  I'm guessing that the next time I call C*D that the GPU no longer needs to be taught what * means and so it will be fast.

But at some point I would imagine the GPU needs to clear out old code so * or other operations not being used at that moment might get flushed from memory, and so later on when the call for A*B happens again there's going to be a penalty in time to recompile it out on the GPU.

Or so I imagine.  If I'm right how do I know when these kernels are going to stick around or disappear?

If I'm wrong and this isn't how it works or there is some other slow step (I'm assuming the data is already transported to arrays on the GPU) then what is this slow step and how does organize things so one pay it as little as possible?

I'm trying to avoid writing explicit numba thread managment kernels as one does in cuda++ but just use the standard numba @njit, @vectorize, @stencil decorators.  Likewise in Cupy I want to just work at the level of the numpy syntax not dive into thread management.

I've read a lot of docs on this but they just refer to overheads of kernels, not when these get paid and how one controls that so I'm confused.

Comment: @talonmies Okay.  Then can you tell me what exists and occurs?  You are right to think I don't have the right mental model as that is what I'm stuggling to learn by asking this question

Comment: Google CUDA context creation and start reading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full answer to this yet. But so far the biggest clue I've gotten has come from reading up on the currently undocumented function `@cupy.fuse()` which makes it more clear than the `@numba.jit` documents where the kernel launch costs are paid. I have not found the connection to Contexts yet as recommended by @talonmies.

see https://gist.github.com/unnonouno/877f314870d1e3a2f3f45d84de78d56c

The key example is this

```
c = cupy.arange(4)
#@cupy.fuse()
def foo(x):
    return x+x+x+x+x
```

foo(.) will be three times slower with @cupy.fuse() commented out because each "+" involves a kernel load and a kernel free.  Fusion merges all the adds into a single kernel so those the launch and free are paid onces.  FOr matricies less than 1 million in size on a typical 2018 GPU, the add() is so fast that the launch and free are the dominate times.

I wish I could find some documentation on @fuse.  FOr example, does it unroll internal functions the way @jit does.  Could I achieve that by stacking @jit and @fuse?

I'm still however largely in the dark about when the costs are getting paid in numba.